# Joining multiple requests into one. Array of observables into an observable of an array

Tags: ios, swift, observable, rx-swift, rxdatasources

I am doing multiple requests for every section that I have in my collectionView.

The idea was to join them together into an Observable<[FeedSection]> so that I can bind it to the collectionView sections.

Right now I am having an array of observables and I don't know how to transform it. Ideas?

So i'm looking into smth like this: `[Observable<FeedSection>] -> Observable<[FeedSection]>`

Code:

```
let feedObservable = [flickrProvider.rx.request(.kittens),
                      flickrProvider.rx.request(.dogs),
                      flickrProvider.rx.request(.publicFeed)].map { 
                          $0.map(Feed.self).asObservable()
}
```

Comment: Please refactor  the title. I've barely processed it :)

Comment: @MikhailKholodkov that's the best I came up with :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do :

```
let feedObservable = [flickrProvider.rx.request(.kittens),
                      flickrProvider.rx.request(.dogs),
                      flickrProvider.rx.request(.publicFeed)]
let zipped = Observable.zip(feedObservable).map { kittens, dogs, public in 
    return [kittens, dogs, public]
}
```